# Should "a lecture on (the) laser technology" have a definite article?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I was tasked to find grammatical error, if any, in below sentence:

> Being a well-known physicist, he (1) was invited to deliver (2) a lecture on laser technology.(3)
> No Error (4)

The correct answer is (4). This sentence doesn't have any error.

But don't you think we should use "the" before laser technology, because it is a specific thing?

Comment: Is it a specific laser technology, such as an individual company's specific type of laser, or is he talking about lasers in general? Without that information, it's impossible to answer, but I'd guess it's more likely to be the general (no article).

Answer (score 1):

*General* studies, such as *geology*, *technology* or *geography* are used without an article.

- Geology is needed for mining.
- The environment is affected by technology.
- Geography determines climate.

*Specific* studies *do* use the definite article.

- The geology of South Africa explains its mineral wealth.
- Using the technology of selective laser sintering decreased engine cost.
- The geography of Tibet attracts climbers.